# query issue in SQL Query for finding empty records

Tags: sql

I have a query in `SQL` where I need to add a condition, to find all the records that have an empty field.

This gave me an error..

```
SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET ==''
```

Thanks

Comment: Change =='' to ='' just one '=' sign, or use the datalength function as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33425/752527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In query use just `=` for checking not `==` and for checking null values use `is null`

```
SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET ='' or SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET is null
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, how can i find now, values that are not empty?

Comment: `is not null` for null values and `!=` for non null values probably

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
I'm accepting it in a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET = '' OR SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET IS NULL
```

The issue is, what does "blank" mean: '' or null or more usually both

Also, use `=` not `==` (I've never actually tried `==`, but I've never seen anyone else either, so it can't be good)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"SELECT 
 forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
  FROM forma 
  LEFT JOIN 
   SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET =''"
```

or try this

```
 WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET is null
```

for not null use

```
WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

to check an empty field, i.e `NULL` field one can't use `=`.
U have to use the `IS NULL`
Your query should be like this

```
SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET 
WHERE SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET IS NULL
```