# How do I retrieve non-empty & non-duplicate data from the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this nitpicked columns on my table (cause the rest are irrelevant in the problem).

```
ID   | Generic Name
-----+---------------
001  | Cetirizine
002  | Cetirizine
003  |
004  | Paracetamol
```

I want my combo box to display only a single entry `Cetirizine` (or any data that has been duplicated) and no empty generic names (some data have no generic names).

I've tried:

```
select 
    Item_GenName 
from 
    ItemMasterlistTable 
where 
    nullif(convert(varchar, Item_GenName), '') is not null
```

but it only achieves the no empty data part.

I've tried using `DISTINCT`, but it doesn't work and somebody suggested `JOIN` but I don't think it works since I'm only using 1 table.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(Item_ID) AS Item_ID, Item_GenName
FROM
    ItemMasterlistTable
GROUP BY 
    Item_GenName
```

but there's always an error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: It would better if you add script (Table and sample data) and expected output

Comment: To get non duplicates in linq you can use a GroupBy and then get the first item from each group.  Null you need to change that the value does not equal Db.Null.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should return only distinct, non-empty Item_GenNames:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Item_GenName
FROM ItemMasterlistTable
// because Item_GenName is of type *text*, the below in lieu of `is not null` and `!= ''`
WHERE datalength(Item_GenName) != 0
```

You said you tried `DISTINCT` and it did not work so I want to clarify,

The `DISTINCT` keyword will return unique records over the complete domain of your select statement.  If you include the ID column in your select statement, even a distinct selection will return your duplicate Item_GenNames b/c the combined ID / Item_GenName record would be unique.  Include only Item_GenName in your select clause to guarantee distinct values for this column.

Comment: The 'text' datatype is deprecated so I don't have much experience with it but you may be able to check for null/empty with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425/2418006).  I will edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: When I tried this on the sql server, it worked! But when I applied it on my c# code, it keeps having this error saying "Column 'Item_GenName' does not belong to table.".

Comment: What I did to fix it was to put "as Item_GenName".

Answer (score 1):

The following query might be useful.

```
    declare @tab table (ID varchar(10), Generic_Name varchar(100))
    insert into @tab
    select '001',   'Cetirizine'
    union 
    select '002',   'Cetirizine'
    union 
    select '003',   ''
    union 
    select '004',   'Paracetamol'

    select MIN(substring(ID, 1, 10)) ID, substring(Generic_Name, 1, 1000) Generic_Name
from @tab
where substring(Generic_Name, 1, 1) <> ''
group by substring(Generic_Name, 1, 1000)
```

Comment: I forgot to put that my ID and Generic Name is formatted as text.
Tried the query below as a test run on the sql server and there's this error: "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Comment: It worked in the sql server but keeps having this error: "Column 'Item_GenName' does not belong to table" when I put it in my c# code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
Select  distinct Item_GenName FROM(
Select * FROM ItemMasterlistTable where Item_GenName <> ''
)t
```

Inner query  remove non-empty records and outer query get the distinct record from the inner output